Right continuity of cdf
Before asking, I want to let you know that I realize already there are different proofs for the right continuity of the cdf, however I would like to know if my proof of this is correct, as I assume it is not since I cannot find any sources doing the same as I..
Here goes nothing. Assuming we are in the discrete case, since for the continuous case one could argue that since it is continuous it is right continuous. To prove right continuity the following must hold $$\forall x_0\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0:x-x_0<\delta\implies |F(x_0)-F(x)|<\varepsilon $$
Now suppose $x_0$ is given, then there must exist some $y$ (greater than $x$) s.t. $P(X\leq x_0)=P(X\leq y)$ See picture for my reasoning.

Let $\delta=\frac{y-x}{2}$, then $x_0+x<y$ if $x-x_0<\delta,$ therefore the right continuity is satisfied since $\delta=\frac{y-x}{2}\implies P(X\leq x_0)=P(X\leq x) \implies |F(x)-F(x_0)|=0<\varepsilon$

It is clearly not general enough.  By the way, whether CDF is right- or left- continuous depends on its definition. See this post for more details.

why is it not general enough? is it my choice of $y$? if so what if we consider $y$ to be the next point where $F$ changes its value i.e. the next point s.t. $F(y)>F(x_0)$? Then by defining the $\delta=\frac{(y-x_0)}{2}$ I obtain what is desired? no? What am I missing. Also my CDF is defined as $P(X\leq x)$

Not all distributions are discrete or continuous: many have both characteristics.

As a general strategy for all such problems, try to illustrate cases that are challenging for your proposed proof method.  For instance, how would your argument work with a Cantor distribution?

The problem is your claim:

Now suppose $x_0$ is given, then there must exist some $y$ (greater than $x$) s.t. $P(X\leq x_0)=P(X\leq y)$

I suppose you mean 'greater than $x_0$', but that does not matter. This already assumes a lot of structure for your cdf, in particular that the values which $X$  can attain do not accumulate right oft $x_0$, see the counter examplet by whuber below this answer.
It does not follow from the definition.
As whuber commented below your question, the cdf can also be a mixture of discrete and continuous, such that it is strictly increasing right of your point $x_0$. Then the $y$ you choose fails to exist, again.

The OP does explicitly assume "the discrete case."  But even then the existence of $y$ is not guaranteed.  A model of the counterexamples is the distribution of $X=1/(1+Z)$ where $Z$ is any non-negative discrete unbounded random variable (like a geometric or Poisson), whence $X$ has a discrete distribution. Taking $x_0=0$ and any $y\gt x_0,$ we have $\Pr(X\le x_0)=0\lt Pr(X\le y)=\Pr(Z\ge 1/(1+y)).$

@whuber I agree. I edited my answer to refer to your example.
